# Lumen 5.6 php artisan migrate --env=testing not working

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, lumen, lumen-5.5

- Lumen Version: 5.6
- PHP Version: 7.2
- Database Driver & Version: SQLite 3

#### Steps To Reproduce:

- cp .env .env.testing
- Set`APP_ENV=testing`
- Run  php artisan migrate --env=testing

**Problem**

Old env file configuration is executing.

Answer (score 3):

First:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

You need to specify the environment before the migrate command.

```
php artisan --env=testing migrate
```

Comment: cache is just fine.  Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Sergio Options for artisan commands are always after : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#options

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. This feature is not there in this lumen version.

[PR LINK FIX](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15629/files)